# How do I create a generic method that takes a two typed lambda expression?

Tags: c#, selenium, lambda

I would like to extend the C# Selenium webdriver action chains such that they have a "WaitFor"   method in the chain.

I have checked out the source for Selenium Webdriver and in looking through it, I've managed to come round to the following block of code:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.PhantomJS;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System;

namespace My.Selenium.Extensions
{
    public class Actions : OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions
    {
        public Actions(IWebDriver driver) : base(driver) { }
        //  NOTE: this line is the GOAL state 
        //     I would like to be able to call to the WebDriver OR to pass in  
        //     an IWebElement along with an anonymous code evaluation
        //     by using the selenium DefaultWait<T> class this should allow
        //     dynamic chaining of events while including waits for more complex
        //     action execution
        //  public Actions WaitFor<T>(T element, Func<T, TResult> condition)

        // NOTE2: this is the only version that will both compile and can be
        //        successfully called via the "test" below
        public Actions WaitFor<T>(T element, Func<T, T> condition)
        {
            DefaultWait<T> wait = new DefaultWait<T>(element);
            wait.Until(condition);
            return this;
        }
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class ActionTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void WaitForTest() {
            IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
            IWebElement bar = driver.FindElement(By.Id("bar"));
            Actions a = new My.Selenium.Extensions.Actions(driver);
            // Note that this will pass the compiler test, but does 
            // not necessarily work as intended
            a.WaitFor(bar, (foo) => { return foo.FindElement(By.CssSelector("table")); } );
            // what I would ideally like to do is more like:
            // a.WaitFor(bar, (bar) => { return bar.GetCssValue("opacity") == "1.0"; } );
        }
    }
}
```

The above code compiles (though I'm not quite as sure that it actually works as intended)

What my eventual goal is to be able to dynamically cook up "waitfor" conditions on the fly using the current C# webdriver "standard" `ExpectedConditions` or my own dynamic evaluations using an `IWebElement` and lambda syntax evaluations.

My problem Appears to be in the declaration of the `WaitFor<T>` class above as a `Func<T,T2>` I am told that the type or namespace T2 could not be found.

The project source is here: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/

With some relevant classes

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/dotnet/src/webdriver/Interactions/Actions.cs

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/dotnet/src/support/UI/DefaultWait.cs

for examples that I'm trying to model on:

Expected Conditions: 
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/dotnet/src/support/UI/ExpectedConditions.cs

and WebDriverWait: 
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/dotnet/src/support/UI/WebDriverWait.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WaitFor` method expects a function that returns the same type of object that it takes as a parameter:

```
public Actions WaitFor<T>(T element, Func<T, T> condition)
```

If you want the supplied function to be a proper conditional, try this version of the method:

```
public Actions WaitFor<T>(T element, Func<T, bool> condition)
{
    DefaultWait<T> wait = new DefaultWait<T>(element);
    wait.Until(condition);
    return this;
}
```

Or for a more generic form (if you'll pardon the pun) you can replace the explicit `bool` with a second generic type placeholder like so:

```
public Actions WaitFor<T, U>(T element, Func<T, U> condition)
{
    DefaultWait<T> wait = new DefaultWait<T>(element);
    wait.Until(condition);
    return this;
}
```